# Cant create a "Serverless VPC Access" on Google Cloud

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google, vpc-peering

I am trying to create a "Serverless VPC Access" on Google Cloud. I have already done it before on another account to join Redis with `CloudRun`.

[This is an example of the configuration that I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS2A0.png)

When the system is creating the connector, I get an [error badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ3ZH.png)
,if I click this red circle I get the following JSON:

```
{
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
status: {
code: 13
message: "An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually."
... 
}
```

I have tried different regions (`us-central1`, `us-west1`, etc...) and different IP ranges (`10.8.0.0/24`, `10.9.0.0/24`, etc). I have tried with different minimums and maximum instances (from 2 to 10 instances). And I've even tried in different days of the week. Some forums say it is because the region is congested.

[This is what I find in Google, there are few results, only 1 page of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPQpW.png)

I found [another forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164378672) where apparently no solution is reached

I suspect that it has to do with the antiquity of the Google Cloud account. Something that happens only for new accounts that have just a few days, because in the old accounts there is no such problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing this issue:

1. Make sure you have sufficient CPU [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota).
2. Check if your Compute Engine Default Service Account is present and enabled. You can [restore](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting) it if it has been deleted less than 30 days ago.
   In case it was longer than that, contact [GCP Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support).